# Nearest point to point, nearest point to line

Tags: algorithm, geometry, complexity-theory, theory, computational-geometry

Imagine a set of `m` points in 2D plane, called "candidates". And then one of two scenarios:

- there is also a set of `n` points ("objects") - see Fig. 1
- there is also a set of `n` lines collinear with X or Y axis ("objects") - see Fig. 2

I would like to know which candidate-object pair has the shortest Cartesian distance of all the pairs.

Please, does anyone know if this problem has a name in computational geometry? Is there algorithm which is faster than O(m*n)? And if objects remain the same, and only candidates change - would it it possible to go faster than O(m*n) by some clever pre-computation?

Fig. 1

```
              c      o
       c
                          o         c      o
           o    c
                             c
              c o              
                       c             o
                                          c
               o                 c
          c
```

Fig. 2

```
             |                      c           |  
-------------+----------------------------------+------  
             |                                  |  
             |              c                   |    c  
             c                                  |  
             |                                  |  
-------------+----------------------------------+------  
             |          c            c          |  
-------------+----------------------------------+------  
             |                            c     |
```

Comment: Is it possible for two objects or lines to be paired with the same candidate?

Comment: Also, do you actually care what the distance is between the object and it's candidate or do you simply care that they're paired together?

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for k-d trees.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: ad your first question: yes, ad the second one: hmm, good question - what the difference? If I know the pair I can compute actual distance very quickly, right?

Comment: Personally I'm thinking of optimizing code. You can avoid the sqrt in the distance formula by simply adding the x offset to the y offset to get a rough estimate of distance. It's not an accurate distance, but it'll save a lot of processing time. Like you said, you can get real distance once they're paired. Before they're paired, there's potentially a lot of distances to be computed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically a nearest neighbour search on all your candidates. You can speed these type of problems up with a [kd tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) index.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get how would you create lines from objects. For every object you create two lines: one vertically and one horizontally, is it?

In any case, assume you have vertical lines v1,v2,..,va and horizontal lines h1,h2,...,hb.

Sort the vertical lines according to their x axis offset and horizontal lines according to their y axis offset.

For every point in candidate set do a binary search to get the nearest vertical and horizontal line. Now it is trivial how you would calculate pair of (candidate,line) that are closest.

Comment: "For every object you create two lines" - no, it is much more simple. There are just bunch of lines, which happen to be axis aligned. And I would like to know which line is the closest one to some point (candidate).

Comment: @EcirHana Then what do objects mean? How are they used? Anyways, my answer should work (input bunch of axis aligned lines and candidate points. I don't know what to do with objects)

Comment: Perhaps the word "object" is a bit confusing, I just wanted one word for both points and lines. So "lines" is in fact "objects", so given a bunch of lines, and bunch of points, what pair has the shortest distance? And for points and points, too...

Answer (score 0):

The name you are looking for is most likely NNS (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) and yes given some time and space for precomputation for a static set of "objects" it should be possible to perform your search faster than O(n*m).

Even using the most simple approach of building a binary search tree you should be able to reduce the the time complexity of a single lookup down to O(log n) leading to O(m log n) for the whole problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have two 1d problems instead of one 2d.
Project all your 'condidates' on x and y axes, then put vertical 'objects' to x axis, horizontal on y.

Voila! two 1d problems.

Now in 1d.

Put all 'condidates' to sorted array, for every 'object' use binary search to find containing segment in that array(two closest 'condidates').

As the result O(n log m + n log n)

Comment: Thanks! But are you sure it works even for Fig. 1? Because by "projecting" it will prefer [taxicab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) distances over the Cartesian ones. (I'm sorry should have been more explicit about this - question edited.)

Comment: @EcirHana Oups, I missed that Fig. 1 is different task =)
In case of points everything becames harder. You could use quadtree-based approach for nearest-neighbour search(e.g FLANN library http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/index.php/FLANN/FLANN) or use point voronoi diagrams http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram (e.g CGAL library http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Voronoi_diagram_2_ref/Chapter_intro.html)